# Gedit bash highlight

Tags: bash, gedit, syntax-highlighting

When I edit bash script(first line is #!/bin/bash) in GEdit, there is no highlighting. But with View->Highlight Mode, there is no result when searching "bash" or "script", which to choose?

Comment: @ user68186 That doesn't work for my Ubuntu. The key seems to be the extension. When I remove .txt, gedit will treat it as bash even it is not executable. As a Windows user, I generally add txt to all generic files in Ubuntu.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `.sh` suffix for scripts instead of `.txt`? There's no harm in having descriptive extensions.

Comment: @Justice for Monica Currently the file is a text file that I used to pass data between Windows host and Ubuntu VM, and this time I pass and edit a script. Will create a .sh for that.

Comment: The first time you save the file, the synthax highlighting will become in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `gedit` there is no `bash` or `script` highlighting mode.  The closest that they have is the `sh` highlight mode.

Plaintext mode:

[image]

View -> Highlight Mode -> sh then select:

[image]

`sh` highlight mode selected:

[image]